# How to get hour from C# DateTime without leading zero?

Tags: c#

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string time = now.ToString("h");
```

errors out saying I should parse the string first. The current time is 3 I don't want 03 I just want 3. `"hh"` returns 03 but I can't simply use `"h".`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
System.DateTime.Now.ToString("%h")
```

You have to [specify that the format is custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers).

Comment: This is the answer. The percent matters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers

Comment: ran into the FormatException error, spent half hour and could not figure it out, google searched, first find was this SO entry, and boom, there is the answer.  Nice!    SO - the way it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want standard `int` formatting.  If so just call `ToString` on the `Hour` property

```
string time = now.Hour.ToString();
```

If you want 12 hour time then do the following

```
var hour = now.Hour > 12 ? now.Hour - 12 : now.Hour;
string time = hour.ToString();
```

Comment: @p.s.w.g how does it fail?

Comment: It's 24 hour time is what he meant. How to convert to 12 hour time?

Comment: @JaredPar It just don't return 12 hour time.  It'll be on a 24 hour clock

Comment: Looks like you can do ((DateTime.Hour + 11) % 12) + 1 to get 12 hour time.

Comment: See TyCobb's answer for the easier solution.